# Python - setuptools - working on two dependent packages (in a single repo?)

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I am working on a python project which contains two modules. The modules are very closely related and hence I want them to be in the same git repo, and to be able to develop them together in my IDE:

- `module1` depends on `module2`
- `module1` has lots of other heavy dependencies, module2 does not
- `module1` and `module2` will be used in different runtime environments
- `module2` should be installable separately so it can run in e.g. an AWS Lambda

Consequently I have tried to set up a project structure which contains the two modules in two folders within one repo, each folder having a `setup.py` so it can packaged. Is this a reasonable approach?

```
\module1
  setup.py
  \module1
    __init__.py
    [scripts].py
\module2
  setup.py
  \module2
    __init__.py
    [scripts].py
```

The above structure should allow me to work on the project locally treating `module2` as a regular module, but the `setup.py` file means that it can be distributed as it's own package, right?

The problem is that I can't include the `module2` dependency in `module1`'s `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="module1",
    version="0.1",
    packages=['module1'], # I really need to include module2 scripts here, right?...
    install_requires=['pandas', 'numpy', ...]
)
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to approach this problem? The two solutions I can guess are:

- Packaging and publishing `module2` on it's own before depending on it from `module1`. This makes development much more infleixble
- Nesting `module2` within `module1` so I can include it in the `packages` argument to the `setup(...)` function. This breaks the clarity that `module1` should be treating `module2` as if it were essentially an external dependency...

Answer (score 4):

Your main reason to keep them in the same repository is to enable parallel work on both the modules in your IDE. I would suggest to keep the modules in separate repositories and use the [editable](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-e) mode for `pip` or [develop](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#development-mode) mode for `setuptools` to achieve the "parallel" development.

Essentially, you would be installing `module2` in a `develop/editable` mode when you use it in `module1`. Thereafter, you will see all the changes made to `module2` immediately while developing `module1`

Doing the same will also make sure that things like `pip install git+<git_directory>` do not break and you can install directly from `git`

Comment: Thanks @Rubbal. So if I was to use two separate repos and setuptools develop mode, how would I declare `module1`'s dependency on `module2` in `setup.py`? I understand using `pip -e [path]`, but what's the equivalent in `setup.py`?

Comment: You will simply add it to `install_requires` (I used to keep a requirements.txt so that I can directly install all requirements while developing. In setup.py, I would parse the requirements.txt and add those to install_requires)

Comment: I think this is probably the right answer (although I never got `install_requires` working properly). I guess my question is really whether there is/should be a mechanism for building more than one PyPI style package from a single set of code. It seems like using setuptools for the build step isn't that flexible...